# CakePHP and set:combine with a default value

Tags: cakephp

i have an array.

At some stage, i'm adding more data to it.

So we have:

```
$editable = someArrayGeneratingFunctionHere();
$points = preg_split('/,/',$this->data['Video']['points']);
```

lovely. Now, the "points" array has a bunch of data that may or may not already be in the editable array. 
What i want is to check if  the data is in editable, and add if not.
I'd like to do this efficiently too.

So, i have this method:

```
private function associateWithRelatedBodyParts($editable, $keysAlreadyPresent, ...){
    $point = getOtherPointsThatAreRelatedToThisPoint();
    if (!isset($keysAlreadyPresent[$point])){
        insertDataIntoEditable();           
    } //else the value is already here. Do not add it again!
    return $editable;
}
```

so the whole thing looks like this:

```
$editable = someArrayGeneratingFunctionHere();
$points = preg_split('/,/',$this->data['Video']['points']);
$valuesInEditable = ...
foreach ($points as $point){ 
    $editable = $this->associateWithRelatedBodyParts($editable, $valuesInEditable,...);
}
```

What a lot of setup! The *whole* point of all this is thus:

i want to flatten the original $editable array, because that way, i can quickly test if a point is in the editable. If it is not, i'll add it.

My current way to retrive the valuesInEditable array is

```
$valuesInEditable = Set::combine($editable, 'BodyPartsVideo.{n}.body_part_id','BodyPartsVideo.{n}.body_part_id');
```

This is moronic. I'm sticking the  same value *twice* into the array. What i'd really like is just:

```
$valuesInEditable = Set::combine($editable, 'BodyPartsVideo.{n}.body_part_id',True);
```

or something like that. So the whole point of this question is:

how do i set a default value using Set:combine in cakephp. If you have a better suggestion, i'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the structure of your array, it seems like you are going through a lot of work to combine the two arrays. Is there a reason you cannot use

```
$final_array = array_merge($points, $editable);
```

before running the set combine?